# Receiving Delivery of Sent Messages in aSmack

Tags: android, xmpp, asmack

I am on last Steps of my Chat app, i'm trying to receive Notification whenever Messages are Delivered, so i found this implementation:

```
 MessageEventRequestListener
```

which comes with 4 overrides:

```
 @Override
public void deliveredNotificationRequested(String from, String packetID,
    MessageEventManager messageEventManager) {
System.out.println("delievered");

}


@Override
public void displayedNotificationRequested(String from, String packetID,
    MessageEventManager messageEventManager) {
System.out.println("displaydelievered");

}


@Override
public void composingNotificationRequested(String from, String packetID,
    MessageEventManager messageEventManager) {
System.out.println("composingdelievered");

}


@Override
public void offlineNotificationRequested(String from, String packetID,
    MessageEventManager messageEventManager) {
System.out.println("offlinedelievered");

}
```

but when a message is sent, nothing happened, i'm wondering am i missing any thing? is this the right approach ? thanks

Answer (score 3):

As @Flow said,XEP-22: Message events is deprecated.You can use DeliveryReceiptManager.

The listener invoked when message received at receiver side

```
  DeliveryReceiptManager.getInstanceFor(connection).addReceiptReceivedListener(new ReceiptReceivedListener()
     {
 @Override
        public void onReceiptReceived(String arg0, String arg1, String arg2) {
            Log.i("Message Delivered  To=", arg0 + ", From =  " + arg1 + " , ID= " + arg2);
        }
    });
}
```

while sending message add following code

```
  //add delivery receipt request

    DeliveryReceiptManager.addDeliveryReceiptRequest(Message);
```

In PacketListener add following code

```
Packet received = new Message();

received.addExtension(new DeliveryReceipt(packet.getPacketID())); 

received.setTo(packet.getFrom());

connection.sendPacket(received);
```

Answer (score 1):

[XEP-22: Message events](http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0022.html) is deprecated, I don't recommend using it. Use Delivery Receipts (XEP-0184) instead: https://www.igniterealtime.org/builds/smack/docs/latest/javadoc/org/jivesoftware/smackx/receipts/DeliveryReceiptManager.html

Answer (score 1):

First add these to your configuration-

```
DeliveryReceiptManager.setDefaultAutoReceiptMode(DeliveryReceiptManager.AutoReceiptMode.always);
ProviderManager.addExtensionProvider(DeliveryReceipt.ELEMENT, DeliveryReceipt.NAMESPACE, new DeliveryReceipt.Provider());
ProviderManager.addExtensionProvider(DeliveryReceiptRequest.ELEMENT, DeliveryReceipt.NAMESPACE, new DeliveryReceiptRequest.Provider());
```

Then after XMPPTcpConnection established add these-

```
DeliveryReceiptManager deliveryReceiptManager = DeliveryReceiptManager.getInstanceFor(this.connection);
deliveryReceiptManager.setAutoReceiptMode(DeliveryReceiptManager.AutoReceiptMode.always);
deliveryReceiptManager.autoAddDeliveryReceiptRequests();
```

This will enable delivery receipt for all messages.

```
SENT:
<iq to='chat_host' id='o2huU-440' type='get'><query xmlns='http://jabber.org/protocol/disco#info'></query></iq>

RECV:
<iq from='chat_host'id='o2huU-440' to='userJID'type='result'><query xmlns='http://jabber.org/protocol/disco#info'> <feature var='urn:xmpp:receipts'/></query>
```

For auto receipt mode all message will be sent with a receipt request extension. And you will get delivery receipt for all messages.

Answer (score 0):

For each message you send, you may send notifications requests with :

```
   MessageEventManager.addNotificationsRequests(message,
                                true, true, true, true);
```

Answer (score 0):

use this code where you get packet of message.
//checking is deliverd or not.

```
if(msg.getBody().toString().equalsIgnoreCase("RecivedByReciver")){

//do what you want after get notify. 

}else{
//do what you want if not delevery report message.
Message message=new Message(ConnectionManager.parseBareAddress(msg.getFrom()),Message.Type.chat);
message.addBody(null,"RecivedByReciver");
Connection().sendPacket(message);

}
```